# Testing local state using `evt.target.name` doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

When running enzyme specs, I have this spec that I can't seem to pass using `evt.target.name` in my event handler. The spec looks like this:

```
describe('<CampusInput /> component', () => {

  let renderedCampusInput
  let campusInputInstance

  beforeEach(() => {
    renderedCampusInput = shallow(<CampusInput />)
    campusInputInstance = renderedCampusInput.instance()
  })

  it.only('handleChange should update the local state', () => {
    renderedCampusInput.find('input').simulate('change', {
      target: { value: 'Another Campus Name' }
    })
    expect(campusInputInstance.state.name).to.equal('Another Campus Name')
  })
})
```

My component looks like this:

```
export default class CampusInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(evt) {
    // this line doesn't pass the spec :(
    this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value })

    // this passes the spec
    this.setState({ name: evt.target.value })   
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          name="name"
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.name}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I can only get it to pass if I hard-code the key in my `setState()`. How can I re-write the specs so that it passes if I use `setState({[evt.target.name]: evt.target.vale})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are expecting name of the input to equal it's value , the second thing is you didn't add the **name** key to the **event** object .

In order to solve this we need to add the name key to the event in your test:

```
renderedCampusInput.find('input').simulate('change', {
     target: { name:'name',value: 'Another Campus Name' }
})
```

and change the expect method to equal **'name'**

```
expect(campusInputInstance.state.name).to.equal('name')
```

also you can add expect **value** of the input

```
expect(campusInputInstance.state.value).to.equal('Another Campus Name')
```

but don't forget to add it to the component state

```
  this.state = {
      name: '',
      value:'',
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.